# Monitor RAID volume, check hard disk health

Tags: hard-drive, raid, snmp

Trying to monitor the RAID volume using SNMP. Is there a command which can parse through the complete RAID volume and output the status of disks in it?

If not SNMP, please suggest a better way to monitor health of hard-disks on the server. (got a failed disk)

***FYI***: appreciate if it not third-party tools. I went through several documents which help to monitor using OID's

Comment: What OS? What RAID?

Comment: OS is CentOS 7 and using Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you `smartctl` from `smartmontools` is able to see hard disk info through various hardware RAID controllers. For example, for Symbios/LSI/Avago MegaRAIDs and recent Dell PERCs:

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sda -d megaraid,0
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.18-1-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" DT01ACA... Desktop HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
Serial Number:    Z5ORUM4KS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 fe3ca6054
Firmware Version: MX6OABB0
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 27 09:54:22 2019 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Here we use any /dev/sdX which got served by this particular RAID controller, and `-d` sets a protocol, where we call for device 0 over protocol `megaraid`. (It uses `megaraid` or `megaraid_sas` driver special call for this.) This 0 is the device ID we see also with `megacli` utility:

```
# megacli -pdlist -a0 

Adapter #0

Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 0
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 0
WWN: 5000039fe3ca6054
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SATA

Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d400000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: ABB0
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x4433221104000000
Connected Port Number: 1(path0) 
Inquiry Data:            Z5ORUM4KSTOSHIBA DT01ACA300                      MX6OABB0
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :37C (98.60 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Drive's NCQ setting : N/A
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No

...
```

See `man smartctl`, `megacli -h` and manuals on https://hwraid.le-vert.net/ for much more details.

I never had to monitor this with SNMP. I didn't heard anybody monitors their Linux systems with raw SNMP. Everywhere I have Linux, I monitor it zabbix-agent, which is much easier to setup when you have many systems with distinct requrements. I only have to use SNMP for systems for which there is no zabbix-agent, this includes various switches, routers and so on.

However, it is possible to script `net-snmp` toolset so it will present any information via SNMP. This includes `smartctl` and `megacli` output. This is very much work, though.

And, about third-party: zabbix and smartmontools is not more third-party than net-snmp, these are FOSS software and, for example, all are available in the default Debian installation, which has strict license requirements. All of them likely to be in CentOS too. But megacli is proprietary, if you want to control and monitor your RAID controller from within OS, you have to agree with that. There is no other way to do things that megacli allows you.